# Sample of an EditText of the BaseUrl of Retrofit Client

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Can anyone help me or give me a sample source code because I cannot find any source about my problem. So basically what I'm trying to do is I'm getting a request using a retrofit client to my server and my `baseurl` is hardcoded one. what if I want to change other server I cannot just change it through my codes then run it again. What I'm planning to do is add an `edittext` that will be able to change `baseurl` so i dont have to hardcode it everytime. Highly appreciate for your help I'm still in a learning process here bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the base url dynamically as:

```java
public interface ApiInterface{  

    @GET // or @Post
    public Call<ResponseBody> request(@Url String url);
}
```

Now the parameter url is your server's url